# “SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module”: occurs on Ubuntu, but not on Windows

Tags: nodejs, javascript

I work with this assembly: https://github.com/andreyalexeich/gulp-scss-starter

It works for me on Windows. But on Ubuntu, right after the run command (`gulp`, or `npm run dev`, or `yarn run dev`) does not start and gives the following error:

```
paranoic:~/PhpstormProjects/20_18$ gulp
[14:27:25] Requiring external module @babel/register
/home/paranoic/PhpstormProjects/project10/gulpfile.babel.js:3
import gulp from "gulp";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Everywhere they write that these are troubles with babel. But why are they on one OS and not the other?

I have already taken the following measures, but they did not work:

- Just in case, I checked some other assembly is running on Ubuntu.
  There is an assembly without imports - it starts
- I changed the version of node to the one that supports modules and
  added an entry "type": "module" to the package

**What should I do to make the build work on Ubuntu?**

Comment: The link provided has documentation in Russian. Can you tell us what command you run and you end up having this issue? import is ES6 syntax and it's not there in node yet. That's the reason there is babel. But we need to understand this better as when you're getting this issue.

Comment: Verify the node version in Windows and Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @JijoJoseph, the error occurs immediately after launch. Updated second paragraph and error text. On Windows, the version of NodeJS is v12.18.3. On Ubuntu I tried to run on versions v8.12.0, v12.18.3, v14.15.0, but to no avail

Comment: I cloned the project and did run without any problem. Node version v12.20.0, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. All I did was 1) cloned the project. 2) npm install 3)sudo npm install gulp-cli -g 4) gulp. What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @JijoJoseph, Ubuntu version 20.04.1 LTS. Probably the best solution is reinstalling Linux. Thank you for such participation in solving my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional information - comments are not intended for this purpose.